# Can I use an at (@) sign in the path part of an url

Tags: url

I know it can't be part of the authority section as usernames with an @ are used there, but can I use it in the path section.

The reason I want to use it is as part of an url for a users resources. eg

www.example.com/user@domain.com/someresource

Comment: A comprehensive answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19737890/133665

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The @ symbol is a reserved character in [RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986) so it is not allowed in your URL. It would be converted to %40 when URL encoding is used.

Comment: I was going to say similar. But then started trying to decide what "If data for a URI component would conflict with a reserved
   character's purpose as a delimiter ..." is trying to highlight. And then, of course, `/` is also a reserved character, and I'm fairly sure you're allowed those in a URL.

Comment: `/` is allowed when being used for its reserved purpose. It is the same for `@` which can be used in the authority part of the URI, but not anywhere else.

Answer (score 3):

In your case, best practice for RESTful and nice URLS, it should be
www.example.com/domain.com/user/someresource